# The graph of $f$ lies on a parabola through $(0,0)$ and $(4,2)$. The function $g$ is the composition of $f$ with itself, which points lie on $g$?

Tags: functions

Let $f$ be a function such that the graph of $f$ lies on a parabola through $(0,0)$ and $(4,2)$. If the function $g$ is the composition of $f$ with itself, which of the following could lie on $g$?

$$(A) (1,1)   \hspace{1cm} (B)(16,2) \hspace{1cm} (C)(8,8) \hspace{1cm} (D)A \text{ or } B  \hspace{1cm} (E)B \text{ or } C$$
I did:

Suppose the function $f=y$ can be any of these two forms as:
$$y=ax^2 \text{ or } x=by^2$$
Plug in those two given points we have 
$$a=\frac{1}{8} \text{ or } b=1$$
so $g$ has two optins
$$g_1=f_1(f_1)=\frac{x^4}{8^3}$$
$$g_2=f_2(f_2)=x^{1/4}$$
which means $(8,8)$ is on $g_1$, $(1,1) $ and $(16,2)$ is on $g_2$. So all of $A,B,C$ are right. But the solution is $E$. I do not know why $A$ is not right. Any help?

Comment: The general form of a parabola is:
$$
f(x) = a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_{0},
$$
where $a_0, a_1, a_2$ are constant.  The forms you wrote down capture only some of the possible parabolas, and probably do not capture the one you need.

Comment: What do you mean by "$f$ is a function"? What is its domain?  In particular, your second form $x = by^2$ does not make sense for a function defined on all the real line.